# Read blurry barcode in python with pyzbar

Tags: python, opencv, image-processing, barcode, zbar

I have been trying to read some barcodes from images uzing Python and pyzbar. Unfortunately, the images are taken from several feet away under several constraints and I cannot move or zoom the camera any closer. Is it possible to read barcodes this blurry using any existing Python libraries?

[image]

So far I've tried some preprocessing including thresholding, sharpening, applying a vertical closing filter, and Wiener filtering, but none seem to help. I am probably asking for a miracle, but if you have any suggestions I would really appreciate it.

Code (commented sections are preprocessing methods I have tried with no success):

```
import numpy as np
import cv2 as cv
from pyzbar import pyzbar

barcode_img = cv.imread('barcode_example.jpg', cv.IMREAD_GRAYSCALE)

# threshold
# (_, barcode_img) = cv.threshold(barcode_img, 0, 255, cv.THRESH_BINARY + cv.THRESH_OTSU)

# close
# barcode_img = cv.morphologyEx(barcode_img, cv.MORPH_CLOSE,
#                               cv.getStructuringElement(cv.MORPH_RECT, (1, 21)))

# sharpen
# barcode_img_blur = cv.GaussianBlur(barcode_img, (15, 1), 3)
# barcode_img = cv.addWeighted(barcode_img, 1.5, barcode_img_blur, -0.5, 0)

# wiener filter
# from skimage import img_as_float
# from skimage.restoration import wiener, unsupervised_wiener
# dim = 3
# psf = np.ones((dim, dim)) / dim ** 2
# barcode_img = wiener(barcode_img, psf, 1.0, clip=False)

barcodes = pyzbar.decode(barcode_img)
print(barcodes)
```

Comment: do you know the type of the barcode?

Comment: I believe code128.

Answer (score 5):

- This solution might not be optimal, but it somehow solves the problem.
- Using statistics knowing that it's a **barcode** where the **vertical black pixels** represent each bar, I did the **summation of the rows**, and thresholded the whole image depending on an empirical value near the **mean of the summation**, then reconstructed the bars accordingly, Here is the solution:

```
#========================
# Import Libraies
#========================
import numpy as np
import cv2 as cv
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt 
from pyzbar import pyzbar

#------------------------
# Read Image
#========================
img = cv.imread('barcode_example.jpg', cv.IMREAD_GRAYSCALE)

# #------------------------
# # Morphology
# #========================
# # Closing
# #------------------------
closed = cv.morphologyEx(img, cv.MORPH_CLOSE, cv.getStructuringElement(cv.MORPH_RECT, (1, 21)))

# #------------------------
# # Statistics
# #========================
print(img.shape)
dens = np.sum(img, axis=0)
mean = np.mean(dens)
print(mean)

#------------------------
# Thresholding
#========================
thresh = closed.copy()
for idx, val in enumerate(dens):
    if val< 10800:
        thresh[:,idx] = 0

(_, thresh2) = cv.threshold(thresh, 128, 255, cv.THRESH_BINARY + cv.THRESH_OTSU)

#------------------------
# plotting the results
#========================
plt.figure(num='barcode')

plt.subplot(221)
plt.imshow(img, cmap='gray')
plt.title('Original')
plt.axis('off')

plt.subplot(224)
plt.imshow(thresh, cmap='gray')
plt.title('Thresholded')
plt.axis('off')

plt.subplot(223)
plt.imshow(thresh2, cmap='gray')
plt.title('Result')
plt.axis('off')

plt.subplot(222)
plt.hist(dens)
plt.axvline(dens.mean(), color='k', linestyle='dashed', linewidth=1)
plt.title('dens hist')

plt.show()

#------------------------
# Printing the Output
#========================
barcodes = pyzbar.decode(thresh2)
print(barcodes)
```

[image: solution]

The Output is:

> `[Decoded(data=b'00004980072868003004', type='CODE128', rect=Rect(left=34, top=0, width=526, height=99), polygon=[Point(x=34, y=1), Point(x=34, y=99), Point(x=560, y=98), Point(x=560, y=0)])]`

Comment: Excuse me , what else in daily life can be applied by this method? Thank you.

Comment: @ABCDEFG user157844 I didn't get your question, can you please elaborate more?

Comment: for example , can we bring this method  to improve documents photo or anything like this. Thank you.

Comment: @ABCDEFGuser157844 I'm not sure if it can be used with documents as the letters don't have simple bar shapes, but maybe to extract the external documents boundaries and make a projection into rectangular shape where the lines can be straight and easily detected and interpreted by ocr algorithms, but that won't be a straight forward implementation, it requires more work on the method.