# How can I find vertical lines in the image? (Opencv and Python) Total vertical avalanche needs fine

Tags: python, opencv, image-processing

**Hi Everyone**,

**I need mark the vertical lines in the picture and find the number.In the example I have done below, I cannot mark exactly.So I find the number of vertical lines wrong.I should draw the lines straight but I couldn't draw
Where could I be wrong ?**

[image]

**the result ı found(Wrong)**
`print(len(contours))` 
`25` 
**Correct Result** = **(22)**

```
import cv2
import numpy as np
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt
# Functions

def resizewithAspectRatio(img,width=None,height=None):
    return cv2.resize(img,(width,height),cv2.INTER_LINEAR)


#------------------------

img=resizewithAspectRatio(cv2.imread("1.jpg"),640,640)
gray_img=resizewithAspectRatio(cv2.cvtColor(img,cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY),640,640) 

empty_img=np.zeros((640,640),np.uint8)+255
kernel = np.ones((5,5),np.uint8)
kernel_size = (3,3)
#Apply Filter

gray_img=cv2.medianBlur(gray_img,3)
gray_img = cv2.bilateralFilter(gray_img,9,75,75)


#--------------------------

threshold = cv2.adaptiveThreshold(gray_img,255,cv2.ADAPTIVE_THRESH_GAUSSIAN_C,\
            cv2.THRESH_BINARY_INV,83,3)


Reverse_img=np.where(threshold==255, 0, 
         (np.where(threshold==0, 255, threshold)))



closing = cv2.morphologyEx(Reverse_img, cv2.MORPH_CLOSE, kernel,iterations=2)


edges = cv2.Canny(closing,50,150,apertureSize = 3)
linesP = cv2.HoughLinesP(edges, 1, np.pi / 180, 50, None, 1, 100)
    
if linesP is not None:
    for i in range(0, len(linesP)):
        l = linesP[i][0]
        cv2.line(empty_img, (l[0], l[2]), (l[3], l[4]), (0,0,255), 4, cv2.LINE_AA)





cv2.imshow("ıM",empty_img)


contours,hierarchy=cv2.findContours(empty_img,cv2.RETR_EXTERNAL,cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE)
print(len(contours))



titles=['Org_Img','threshold','Reverse_img','closing','empty_img']
images=[img,threshold,Reverse_img,closing,empty_img]
for i in range(5):
    plt.subplot(3,3,i+1),plt.imshow(images[i] , 'gray')
    plt.title(titles[i])
    plt.xticks([]),plt.yticks([])
    
plt.show()
```

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: It's probably easier to work with a cropped version of the image (only part of the height). That way, you have less issues with the 'vertical lines' actually being pretty bendy and not straight lines at all.

Answer (score 1):

Please see my [other answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/64175996) for further explanation.

[image: Result]

```py
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import cv2

# Read image
img = cv2.imread('input.jpg', 0)

# #------------------------
# # Morphology
# #========================
# # Closing
# #------------------------
closed = cv2.morphologyEx(img, cv2.MORPH_CLOSE, cv2.getStructuringElement(cv2.MORPH_RECT, (1, 7)))

# #------------------------
# # Statistics
# #========================
dens = np.sum(img, axis=0)
mean = np.mean(dens)

#------------------------
# Thresholding
#========================
thresh = 255 * np.ones_like(img)
k = 0.9
for idx, val in enumerate(dens):
    if val< k*mean:
        thresh[:,idx] = 0

thresh = 255 - thresh
contours,hierarchy=cv2.findContours(thresh,cv2.RETR_EXTERNAL,cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE)
count = len(contours)


#------------------------
# plotting the results
#========================
plt.figure(num='{} Lines'.format(count))

plt.subplot(221)
plt.imshow(img, cmap='gray')
plt.title('Original')
plt.axis('off')

plt.subplot(223)
plt.imshow(thresh, cmap='gray')
plt.title('Thresholded')
plt.axis('off')

plt.subplot(224)
plt.imshow((thresh/255)*img, cmap='gray')
plt.title('Result')
plt.axis('off')

plt.subplot(222)
plt.hist(dens)
plt.axvline(dens.mean(), color='k', linestyle='dashed', linewidth=1)
plt.title('dens hist')

plt.show()
```

Comment: Hi , @bilal  This is a fabric picture. Vertical thread is always present in fabrics. How can I dynamically use this solution for pictures like this ?

Comment: @BilalKAYIRAN can you provide more fabric images that this algorithm can't handle correctly, of course this solution isn't general, but I need more details and images to understand the problem perfectly.

Comment: ok.I'll ready the images.I'll give detail with images to you.thank you for your interest @bilal

Comment: hi again @bilal :)  I added two new pictures inside the subject.

Comment: @BilalKAYIRAN The code is still valid for the image before the last one with count of 72, the last image, the lines are not vertical anymore, the slope exceeds the tolerance to say "Vertical", I tell you again that this code isn't general, for different kinds of textures, you might need to change the parameter 'k', and if there was a slope above some limit in the "Vertical" lines, they will not be vertical or valid for this code anymore.