# remove the white rectangle part of the image and merge the remaining image

Tags: python, python-3.x, opencv, image-processing

I have a grayscale image and want to remove the white rectangle from the image and join the upper and lower images.
The input image is[image]
The output image should look like[image]

Code that I have done so far

```py
image = cv2.imread('./rotated_image.png')

mask = np.zeros(image.shape[:2], np.uint8)

backgroundModel = np.zeros((1, 65), np.float64)
foregroundModel = np.zeros((1, 65), np.float64)
 
rectangle = (78, 10, 971, 30)
 
cv2.grabCut(image, mask, rectangle, backgroundModel, foregroundModel,5, cv2.GC_INIT_WITH_RECT)
 
mask2 = np.where((mask == 2)|(mask == 0), 0, 1).astype('uint8')

image = image * mask2[:, :, np.newaxis]
plt.imshow(image)
plt.show()
cv2.imwrite("op.png", image)
```

so the output is:

[image: img]

After that, I tried subtracting from the main image

```py
image1 = cv2.imread('./rotated_image.png')
image2 = cv2.imread('./op.png')
subtracted = cv2.subtract(image1, image2)
plt.imshow(subtracted)
plt.show()
cv2.imwrite("sub.png", subtracted)
```

The output is [image]

So, the white rectangle becomes black but I want to remove it and merge the image.

Comment: Ok, so where are you having trouble? What have you tried? You are supposed to do your own research and develop your own approach. Stack Overflow is not a free coding service.

Comment: I have tried thresholding and making the white part black but the problem is I am unable to remove that particular part.

Comment: Thresholding is a good start. Maybe use Otsu's Thresholding to segment the brightest part of the image. Get its contour and then its bounding box. Now, with this info you estimate two bounding boxes more: one for the top part and another for the bottom part. Crop the two parts and merge them in a new image.

Comment: I have tried using the grabcut method.But I am confused here.

Comment: @KrupaliMistry you can **sum** the row values, and for a specified **threshold** you can delete that row to remove the white and keep the gray region.

Comment: you talk of removing entire rows of pixels. that means you need to slice and concatenate/vconcat/vstack.

Comment: @ChristophRackwitz I want to remove the white part from the image and merge the remaining image

Comment: @Bilal can you give an example of summing the values and thresholding it

Comment: @KrupaliMistry here is an [example with barcode](https://stackoverflow.com/a/64175996), the same approach is applicable here.